# TouchableHighlight one click not work two works

Tags: ios, react-native

I am having a strange problem. I wrote up a simple player app with react native and everything is fine in simulator. But when it comes to real device, its play button does not work properly. I tried the app on iPhone 6s and iPhone 5. The problem is that the play button works at second tap. The first tap does nothing.

Here is my whole render code:

```
render() {
    let playIcon = this.state.isPlaying ? 'pause' : 'play';
    let titleA = 'Set A: ' + (this.state.isASet ? this._toTime(this.state.pointA) : '-');
    let titleB = 'Set B: ' + (this.state.isBSet ? this._toTime(this.state.pointB) : '-');
    let time = this._toTime(this.state.time);
    let remaining = this._toTime(this.state.duration - this.state.time);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.info}>
          <Text>Name: {this.props.song.name}</Text>
          <Text>Artist: {this.props.song.artist.name}</Text>
          <Text># of channels: {this.props.song.tracks.length}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.channels}>
          {
            this.props.song.tracks.map((track, index) => {
              return (
                <VolumeSlider
                  key={index}
                  title={track.name}
                  volume={this.state.channelVolumes[index]}
                  onVolumeChange={this._handleChannelVolumeChange.bind(this, index)}
                  onMutePress={this._handleChannelMutePress.bind(this, index)}
                  onSoloPress={this._handleChannelSoloPress.bind(this, index)}
                  isPlayingSolo={this.state.channelSolos[index]}
                />
              );
            })
          }
          <VolumeSlider
            title='Main'
            volume={this.state.mainVolume}
            onVolumeChange={this._handleMainVolumeChange.bind(this)}
            onMutePress={this._handleMainMutePress.bind(this)}
            hideSolo={true}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this._handleAPress.bind(this)}>
            <Text numberOfLines={1}>{titleA}</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this._handleBPress.bind(this)}>
            <Text numberOfLines={1}>{titleB}</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={this._handleClearLoopPress.bind(this)}
          >
            <Text numberOfLines={1}>Clear</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.player}>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._handlePlayPress.bind(this)}>
            <Icon
              name={playIcon}
              style={styles.playButton}
            />
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <View style={styles.center}>
            <Text style={styles.timelineText}>{time}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
            <Slider
              style={[styles.slider, styles.timelineSlider]}
              onSlidingComplete={this._handleTimelineChange.bind(this)}
              maximumValue={this.state.duration}
              value={this.state.time}
              step={0.01}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.center}>
            <Text style={styles.timelineText}>-{remaining}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

And this is how it looks like on simulator:
[image: Screenshot of the app when the player screen launched]

I tried changing the location of the play button (I mean I placed it at the top of the app) and it worked. But I don't understand why it does not work when it is at bottom-left corner?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is **NavigatorIOS** which is parent of the PlayerScreen of which render function is given belove. The navigator has **swipe back gesture** and it blocks the first tap on the play button. When I disabled the swipe back gesture of the navigator by falsing its **interactivePopGestureEnabled** pro, the play button properly worked.